# what's the cause of the following error

Tags: maven, maven-2

When using Eclispe m2e plugin, Ireceived the following error

Failed to execute goal on project ****: Could not resolve dependencies for project ****: Could not find artifact org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.1 in snapshots (abc)

abc is our maven private repository.

althought httpclient.jar is in my local repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
artifact org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.1 in snapshots (abc)
```

that looks like your confgiguration for SNAPSHOT/RELEASE Repository isn't correct.

Have you checked to build on command line via:

```
mvn clean package
```